# Открывать новый экран, при нажатии ListView

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

Здравствуйте, что только не делал, не получаеться. Нужно открывать новый экран, при нажатии на ListView. Но и передать туда id из (content_contests_list.xml) TextView android:id="@+id/id"

Contests.java

public class Contests extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

```
private String TAG = ContestsView.class.getSimpleName();
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private int offSet = 0;
private ListView lv;

public int OffMoreButtom = 0;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String urlStatic = "https://unkop.com/api/contests?id=9&token=$1$vLyWeNSm$tMhTzT5N7KKu4nznlCZ1Q.&type=2&offset=";
private static String url = "https://unkop.com/api/contests?id=9&token=$1$vLyWeNSm$tMhTzT5N7KKu4nznlCZ1Q.&type=2&offset=0";
private static String ContestsCount = "0";
private static String BackUpCount = "0";
private static String contetsEnd = "0";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contests);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new Contests.GetContacts().execute();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();


    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(R.color.blue, R.color.green, R.color.yellow, R.color.red);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new Contests.CountContests().execute();
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
    );

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttom_new_contests, null);
    lv.addFooterView(view);

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    final NavigationView navigationViewRight = (NavigationView) findViewById(nav_view_right);
    navigationViewRight.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Drawer.openDrawer(nav_view);
            //drawer.closeDrawer(navigationViewRight);
        }
    });
}

public void hideMoreButtom() {
    OffMoreButtom = 1;
}

public void onMyButtonClick(View view)
{
    // выводим сообщение
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Зачем вы нажали?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contests);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new Contests.GetContacts().execute();
}

public void openContestsView(View v){
    Intent toy = new Intent(Contests.this, ContestsView.class);
    startActivity(toy);
}

public void MenuRight(MenuItem item){
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationViewRight = (NavigationView) findViewById(nav_view_right);
    navigationViewRight.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    drawer.openDrawer(navigationViewRight);
}

public void loadNewContests(View view){
    if(OffMoreButtom == 0) {
        new Contests.GetContacts().execute();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contests, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menuRight) {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Зачем вы нажали?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
            .setName("ContestsView Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
            .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
            .build();
    return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
            .setObject(object)
            .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client.connect();
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
    client.disconnect();

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

}


public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Then we get reference for Picasso
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
        if (img == null) {
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivBasicImage);
            v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
        }
        // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
        // do Picasso
        // maybe you could do that by using many ways to start
        String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get("photo");
        boolean ifyoutube = url.contains("/vi/");
        com.squareup.picasso.Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
                .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
                .borderWidthDp(0)
                .cornerRadiusDp(100)
                .oval(false)
                .build();
        if (ifyoutube) {
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transform(transformation)
                    .into(img);
        }
        else {
            url = url.replaceAll(".jpg", "_square.jpg");
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .transform(transformation)
                    .into(img);
        }

        // return the view
        return v;
    }
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
public class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Contests.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                offSet = offSet + 5;
                url = urlStatic + offSet;
                Log.e(TAG, "URL: " + url);
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                contetsEnd = jsonObj.getString("contetsEnd");

                Contests.BackUpCount = Contests.ContestsCount;
                Contests.ContestsCount = jsonObj.getString("Count");
                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contests = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contestsAll");
                //ContestsCount = jsonObj.getString("Count");
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contests.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contests.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String type = c.getString("type");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String text = c.getString("text");
                    String count = c.getString("count");
                    String photo = c.getString("img");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject user_id = c.getJSONObject("user_id");
                    String id_user = user_id.getString("id");
                    String name = user_id.getString("name");
                    String username = user_id.getString("username");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject time = c.getJSONObject("time");
                    String start = time.getString("start");
                    String finish = time.getString("finish");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("type", type);
                    contact.put("title", title);
                    contact.put("text", text);
                    contact.put("count", count);
                    contact.put("id_user", id_user);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("username", username);
                    contact.put("start", start);
                    contact.put("finish", finish);
                    contact.put("photo", photo);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);

                    int BazaId = Integer.parseInt(id);
                    int BazaContetsEnd = Integer.parseInt(contetsEnd);

                    if (BazaId == BazaContetsEnd) {
                        hideMoreButtom();
                    }
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter =
                new Contests.MyAdapter(
                        Contests.this, contactList,
                        R.layout.content_contests_list,
                        new String[]{"ids", "type", "title",
                                "text", "count", "id_user", "name", "username", "start", "finish"}, new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.type,
                        R.id.title, R.id.text, R.id.count,
                        R.id.id_user, R.id.name,
                        R.id.username, R.id.start, R.id.finish});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

private class CountContests extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlStatic+"0");

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "URL: " + urlStatic+"0");
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Contests.BackUpCount = Contests.ContestsCount;
                Contests.ContestsCount = jsonObj.getString("Count");
                Log.e(TAG, "ContestsCount: " + ContestsCount);
                Log.e(TAG, "BackUpCount: " + BackUpCount);
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            int BackCount = Integer.parseInt(BackUpCount);
            int Count = Integer.parseInt(ContestsCount);

            if(BackCount != Count) {
                OffMoreButtom = 0;
                contactList.clear();
                url = urlStatic;
                offSet = 0;
                new Contests.GetContacts().execute();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Contests.this, "Nothing new", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // Activity being restarted from stopped state
}
```

}

content_contests_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivBasicImage"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Title:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Title:"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="11dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Posted by:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="Type:"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Type:"
                android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:text="Date finish:"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/finish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled"
                android:text="26.12.2016"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="sffad fdasf asdf asdfsad f af adsf asdf sdaf dsaf adsf dasf dasf asdfsffad fdasf asdf asdfsad f af adsf asdf sdaf dsaf adsf dasf dasf asdf"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:maxLines="2" />

<Button
    android:text="View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/View"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:onClick="closePreload"
    android:layout_weight="0.10"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/count"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="@color/common_plus_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_user"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

```
    content_contests_view.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_contests"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.unkop.unkop.Contests"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_contests"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#EBEBEB"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp">
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: зачем нужно передавать этот ID виджета, он для всех айтемов списка одинаковый, а вне разметки айтема бесполезен. Может вам нужно передавать ID записи, а не виджета?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- К ListView добавить OnItemClickListener;
- Затем, когда на какой-то из элементов ListView произойдет клик, то получить ссылку на TextView android:id="@+id/id" из нажатого элемента;
- После этого, создать новый Intent для открытия соответствующей Activity, с помощью putExtra положить id из TextView;
- В открытой Activity получить id.

**OnItemClickListener**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView textView_id = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.id));
        Intent i = new Intent(Contests.this, NEW_ACTIVITY.class);
        i.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", textView_id.getText());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

**Получение id в открытой Activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String id = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
```